# Archivos CSS sin Minificar en NUXT

Tags: vue.js, nuxt

tengo una web realiazda con NUXT (framework de VUE) y al compilarla no comprime los archivos CSS dandome un codigo HTML muy largo.

https://www.tiroconarco.link/

Los archivos los genero con un **yarn generate** supongo que debo tener que poner algo en los archivos de configuración para que comprima los CSS.

¿Me podeis ayudar?

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Añadiendo este código en el fichero de configuración **nuxt.config.js** lo he podido solucionar

```
// nuxt.config.js

export default {
  build: {
    extractCSS: true
  }
}
```